# Logging in multiple files with filters which are ignored

Tags: c#, serilog

I have defined two Filters for a serilog `LoggerConfiguration`
Both are RollingFile loggers which should, depending on the type write in a log file in another folder.

```
var activityPath = @"C:\temp\Activities\log-{Date}.log";

var eventsPath = @"C:\temp\Events\log-{Date}.log";

loggerConfig.WriteTo.Logger(
                    lc =>
                        lc.Filter.ByExcluding(Matching.FromSource<EventLogItem>())
                            .WriteTo.RollingFile(pathFormat: eventsPath,
                                fileSizeLimitBytes: 1073741824,
                                retainedFileCountLimit: 31));
loggerConfig.WriteTo.Logger(
                    lc =>
                        lc.Filter.ByExcluding(Matching.FromSource<ActivityLogItem>())
                            .WriteTo.RollingFile(pathFormat: activityPath,
                                fileSizeLimitBytes: 1073741824,
                                retainedFileCountLimit: 31));

_logger.Information("{@ActivityLogItem}", new ActivityLogItem());
_logger.Information("{@EventLogItem}", new EventLogItem());
```

When i'm logging with this configuration both files in both folders are generated but the files contain both the entries for the `EventLogItem` and the `ActivityLogItem`.

**File: Activities\log-2016....log**

> 2016-12-29 17:36:47.610 +01:00 [Information] EventLogItem { Id:
>   00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, TimeStamp: 01/01/0001 00:00:00,
>   Title: "Startup", Detail: "Starting up" } 2016-12-29 17:57:32.297
>
> +01:00 [Information] ActivityLogItem { Ip: "::1", Port: "-1", UserAgent: "Mozilla/5.0", StartRequest: 12/29/2016 17:57:29,
>   EndRequest: 12/29/2016 17:57:29 }

**File: Events\log-2016....log**

> 2016-12-29 17:36:47.610 +01:00 [Information] EventLogItem { Id:
>   00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, TimeStamp: 01/01/0001 00:00:00,
>   Title: "Startup", Detail: "Starting up" } 2016-12-29 17:57:32.297
>
> +01:00 [Information] ActivityLogItem { Ip: "::1", Port: "-1", UserAgent: "Mozilla/5.0", StartRequest: 12/29/2016 17:57:29,
>   EndRequest: 12/29/2016 17:57:29 }

I have also tried it with `ByIncludingOnly` at the Filter configuration, which resulted in the result that no file was generated.

How should my configuration look like that serilog will log on different files for a type?

**Edit:**

I have also tried it now by adding a `Matching.WithProperty`

In my class `ActivityLogItem` I have added a new property:

```
public int EType {get;set;} = 1;
```

and changed the configuration to

```
ByExcluding(Matching.WithProperty<int>("EType", p => p == 1)
```

which is also getting ignored. The logger writes both entries in both files specified.

Comment: maybe duplicate. try http://stackoverflow.com/a/38785632/3762855

Comment: @CiroCorvino I have tried that and also an attempt with `Matching.WithProperty`which also had the same result that the logger writes in both files

Comment: tryed to adding the namespace? The objects to filter are in different assemblies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FromSource()` filter identifies events raised by a particular logger:

```
_logger.ForContext<ActivityLogItem>()
     .Information("This would be picked up by the filters");
```

The `WithProperty()` filter looks at the direct properties on the log events, i.e. the names embedded in the message template like `{@ActivityLogItem}`. In your follow-up edit, the `EType` property is a nested property, so won't match the filter.

You could do the following if you want to use that approach:

```
_logger.Information("{EType} {@ActivityLogItem}", 1, new ActivityLogItem());
```

There are several ways to set up the filtering; I'd recommend the `ForContext()` approach if it is open to you. Alternatively, if you don't want to modify the logging statements, try:

```
Filter.ByExcluding(evt => evt.Properties.TryGetValue("ActivityLogItem"));
```