# Serilog using Microsoft ILogger - logging to different places from one code in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, serilog

I'm using serilog through Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger.
This is my configuration in Program.cs:

```
public class Program
  {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                                          .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                                          .Build();
      Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                     .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
                     .CreateLogger();
      CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
          .UseSerilog()
          .ConfigureLogging((context, logging) =>
          {
            logging.ClearProviders();
            logging.AddSerilog();
          })
          .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
          {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
          });
  }
```

I use the ILogger through DI. Everything works fine. Now I want to log some specific log to some file and some specific log to database. For example I want to log info about something to somewhere and info about something else to somewhere else.

**For example:** I have a game. I want to log names of connected players and their actions to some file and events in the game and errors to a database.

I know how to log into a db and file, but I dont know how can i separate the logs. How can I do it?

This is the config file (right now just for the file sink).

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Error",
        "System": "Error"
      }
    },
    "Enrich": [ "SomeName" ],
    "WriteTo": [
      { "Name": "Console" },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "log.log",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "outputTemplate": "SomeFormat"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Application": "SomeName"
  },
```

Comment: The important part, the Serilog configuration, is missing. As for adding multiple sinks, that's explained in the documentation. Have you tried anything? What does your configuration look like?

Comment: Filtering is also explained in the docs. If you want to log events from different loggers or different levels to different sinks you need to add a filter in the configuration

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I added configuration. I haven't tried anything because I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Check [this sample](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration/blob/dev/sample/Sample/appsettings.json) from the Serilog.Settings.Configuration repo. It shows how to specify multiple loggers with their own MinimumLevel setting.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I dont want to filter it based on minimum level. I want for example some debug to some file and another debug to another file.

Comment: I prefer configuring Serilog in code to be honest. It's a *lot* easier than JSON and in the end, it's *very* rare to use completely different loggers in development, production etc. In most cases, apps use the same loggers and filters, and only change the paths or connection strings from development to production

Comment: And what does `another debug to another file` mean? Another based on what? The logger? Category? Some other context value? It's the same for all of them - you specify a filter in the sublogger

Comment: Check the [Filters](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Configuration-Basics#filters) and [Sub-loggers](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Configuration-Basics#filters) sections in `Configuration Basics`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I dont know options. But the best would be something like log.LogDebug("sink1", "some log message") and it will log through sink1 somewhere.

Comment: That's not how logging works - not just Serilog but *any* logging library. The sinks are specified during configuration *only*. The `Log` call should have *no* knowledge of the sinks, otherwise changing a logger would require changing *all* of your code. When you log something, the logging library logs an event with certain properties like the source logger name, category, level, text etc. The sinks then decide which events to write based on their configuration

Comment: When you use `ILogger<MyController>`, you get a logger whose category is `MyController`. You can create a filter expression that only logs `MyController` messages to a specific sink, everything else to another

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos So let's say I have a game. I want to log names of connected players and their actions to some file and events in the game and errors to a database. How would you do it?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I want to do this also in one class.

Comment: You do realise this is completely different than the original question? Update the question and ask what you *really want*. And read the docs on [Enrichment](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Enrichment) which explains how you can add extra information to a log event

Comment: Unless you update the question, people won't be able to understand what you ask and won't be able to post a good answer. Almost nobody reads comments. Comments can be deleted at any time too. SO is a Q&A site, not a forum, so comments aren't considered important. Some moderator may decide there are too many comments in this thread and copy them to a chat channel, deleting everything here

Answer (score 1):

You could try to write your own sinks.
The LogEvent class offered by Serilog has a custom

```
readonly Dictionary<string, LogEventPropertyValue> _properties
```

which you could use to pass some flags. Based on the flags, your sinks can decide if they act or not upon your message.

But this is all at Serilog lvl. The integration with ILogger might take more thought.

Comment: I have just found this: https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Enrichment. If you checkout the LogContext section, you will see a way to temporarily enrich the logging context, hence making it easy to add/remove those flag markers.

Comment: And another useful link (personally, I like this one better):https://benfoster.io/blog/serilog-best-practices/ Check out the PropertyBagEnricher class and usage of it

Comment: Serilog, like most logging libraries, offers filters for this job. By design, sinks aren't meant to filter anything, only write events to specific targets. It's the filters' job to control which events are sent to each sink

Answer (score 1):

You can store in different sinks by settings [filtering exceptions](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-filters-expressions)

You could filter in many different ways. The one that worked for me was to filter by namespace like:

```
var isController = Matching.FromSource("MyApp.Controllers");
var isService = Matching.FromSource("MyApp.Services");
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
    .WriteTo.RollingFile("d:/logs/recon-api-all-{Date}.log")
    .WriteTo.Logger(l => l
        .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(isController)
        .WriteTo.RollingFile("d:/logs/recon-api-controller-{Date}.log"))
    .WriteTo.Logger(l => l
        .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(isService)
        .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(connectionString: ""))
    .WriteTo.Logger(l => l
        .Filter.ByExcluding(e => isController(e) || iService(e))
        .WriteTo.RollingFile("d:/logs/recon-api-other-{Date}.log"))
    .CreateLogger();
```

You can find a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38760381/multiple-filters-for-one-logger-with-serilog)