# How display only custom logging in Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I  created my own custom loger provider FileLogerProviderr to save logs to file.

I added custom FileLoggerProvider in program.cs:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) => 
                {

                    logging.AddProvider(new FileLoggerProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "logger.txt")));
                    logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.None);

                })
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

To test I added log in controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private ILogger<HomeController> logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> log)
        {
            logger = log;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            logger.LogDebug($"test index path!!!");
            return View();
        }
}
```

Working, But in file except **test index path** I see many additional information. I dont need this information. I need only save in file my log from controller.

```
Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:44339/  
Route matched with {action = "Index", controller = "Home", page = "", area = ""}. Executing action LoggingTest.Controllers.HomeController.Index (LoggingTest)
Executing action method LoggingTest.Controllers.HomeController.Index (LoggingTest) - Validation state: Valid
test index path!!!
Executed action method LoggingTest.Controllers.HomeController.Index (LoggingTest), returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult in 11.8159ms.
Executing ViewResult, running view Index.
Executed ViewResult - view Index executed in 43.4928ms.
Executed action LoggingTest.Controllers.HomeController.Index (LoggingTest) in 224.1184ms
Request finished in 400.2906ms 200 text/html; charset=utf-8
Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:44339/favicon.ico  
Sending file. Request path: '/favicon.ico'. Physical path: 'C:\Users\dborovsky\projects\LoggingTest\LoggingTest\wwwroot\favicon.ico'
Request finished in 39.8394ms 200 image/x-icon
```

How I can solve this? Thank you

**UPDATE**
appsettings.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "CONSTRING"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "None",
      "System": "None",
      "Microsoft": "None"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35251078/how-to-turn-off-the-logging-done-by-the-asp-net-core-framework 

If you don't think it is, please post your appsettings.json file

Comment: i have already updated with appsetings.josn. check please. I just set None.

Comment: 1. You didn't add a logging configuration by `logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));` 2. Make sure you've changed the `appsettings.Development.json` (or `appsettings.Production.json` if in production environment).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you´ll like to use a configuration to prevent all events gets logged.

I recommend you inject the logger in ConfigureServices (.ConfigureLogging from Program.cs at least you want to log web hosting events):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddLogging(loggers=> 
            {
                loggers.AddConsole();
                loggers.AddDebug();
                loggers.AddProvider(new FileLoggerProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "logger.txt")));
            });


            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        }
```

Then you´ll can configure as follows (make sure you have the enviroment variant properly configurated):

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "CONSTRING"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "None",
      "Microsoft": "None"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

And the implementation:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private ILogger<HomeController> logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> log)
        {
            logger = log;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            logger.LogDebug($"test index path!!!");
            return View();
        }
}
```

Here is as pretty nice Microsoft´s article about logging:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.2